# How to protect my home against spying?

Tags: security

My personal information has been stolen and used to commit fraud a couple of times... vigillence has allowed me to not get hit too badly but it's becomming a real chore, consuming lots of my time. Last time (this week), it seems that my wife's phone was cloned and used to access our banking info.

With surveillance equipment and techniques being used by criminals, what are some things that I can do to protect my privacy and information in the home? For example, a bit of cold war tech used the vibrations in incandescent light bulbs from to eavesdrop on conversation with a telescope; also, special microphones could be attached to copper pipes and wires with the same result, not to mention hidden cameras and computer viruses. I don't have any incandescent bulbs or copper pipes... but the fact is, that technology is making home invasion and espionage an activity performed from across the street with some regularity (as evidenced by the slew of commercials for credit protection on TV).

Obviously, internet security and credit card alerts and such are not home improvements... this question is asking for ways to (help) secure the home with respect to spying.

Comment: [Tempest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempest_(codename))

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick There's not much you can do about the government. It's the zealots and desperate people that are causing more personal problems.

Comment: 99% of this type of problem is user error (poor passwords, falling prey to phishing emails). Fortifying your home doesn't seem like a practical approach. If you're truly being targeted in such a way, call the police or the FBI.

Comment: I doubt your wife's phone was "cloned". It's very easy to set up a VOIP (voice over IP) line to report any desired number as the caller ID. All the crook needed was her cell phone number (presumably easy to find).

Comment: @isherwood there are a couple people in jail now from a previous issue, but international laws are basically ineffective. The world is getting smaller.

Comment: We don't know your threat vectors, which derive from your life situation.  Torrenting movies?  Retired super-spy?  Insist on doing online banking?  Run a Bitcoin trading post?  Tend to draw stalkers?  All require dramatically different protection strategies. If you're just blind to the actual risk matrix because you've been whipped into a frenzy, question the motives of the whipper.

Comment: For data security, ask on the security (infosec) SE.  You didn't ask about anti-burglary, which would be on-topic here.  Other than that, the #1 infosec problem is people grabbing your postal mail.  Use a PO box or better, a Private Mail Box (PMB) such as the UPS store: Fedex/UPS deliver to them, they can forward your mail, 24hr access, and businesses who hate PO boxes accept them.  Even utilities who know your physical address will send your bill there if you ask.

Comment: @harper For me the issue is monetary (usually). I'm tired of dealing with that (third time's the charm). But I also happen to deal with sensitive info. I guess you could say that I'm kind of wondering what other people think (or know) about protecting their homes from what is essentially espionage. Many never deal with it... but then again, maybe this issue just a little ahead of it's time. I think it could be a significant issue for many now, and in the future. There are high profile people, as well as low profile people of interest, facilities, and corporations that utilize safeguards.

Comment: Try it yourself, get some gear and surveil someone else.  You'll figure out right quick that surveillance is HARD.  It's not even the money, it's the TIME, and oh, the boredom!  So realistically threat-assess: Why would someone consider surveilling you to be the single best use of their time? For most consumers, the answer is "there is no reason".  Which means it isn't happening!  The internet age doesn't help automate individual home surveillance, but it does automate so many other mass attacks (e.g. scraping Facebook), so they go there instead.

Comment: @harper I used to have the same philosophy. When I was a kid, we left our doors unlocked.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are specifically being targeted, the majority of "security measures" will most likely be unnecessary/unrealistic.

Regardless, the methods/options of securing a home or structure are likely too numerous to effectively create an answer for this site.

If you are convinced you need to secure your home against the KGB, NSA, or your creepy neighbor, there are some basic measures you could take.

- [Window film for privacy](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Decor-Blinds-Window-Treatments-Window-Film/N-5yc1vZarc3)
- Better door locks such as [ANSI Grade 1 door locks](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Tools-Hardware-Hardware-Door-Knobs-Hardware-Door-Locks-Deadbolts/ANSI-Grade-I-(Best)/N-5yc1vZc223Z1z0w23r)
- A way to securely destroy sensitive items/documents (shredder, fire pit)
- Avoid any network-based security system (smart-home items included)
- Use a P.O. box for all  mail.
- [Signal Jammers](http://www.jammerall.com/categories/WIFI-Jammer/) to prevent unwanted snooping (although this will block your own as well)
- [Military grade mobile jammer](http://www.srcinc.com/what-we-do/ew/crew-duke.html) (jammers are not legal in the US)
- Only use cash, eliminate credit cards and bank transactions
- Live off-grid
- Avoid all contact with civilization (electronic and personal)
- Be under [witness protection](http://www.usmarshals.gov/witsec/), get new identity

Comment: Might also consider using a paper shredder on sensitive documents.

Comment: Locking mailbox would be a good addition, or a mail slot in the door so someone can't walk up and grab your credit card statement.  Security cameras can alert you if anyone is being suspicious around your home.

Answer (score 3):

The slew of commercials is mostly about making money off fear, and has nothing to do with your household security.

As an information professional, I do not have online access to my bank accounts, and have never found that to be a particularly attractive thing to have. If you don't want the horses stolen, don't cut extra barn doors leading directly to rustler's gulch....

Purchase and religiously use a crosscut shredder. Most people throw away or recycle far too much personal information in readable form. If anyone has time or money to reassemble that, you have worse problems.

After that, Look deeply in a mirror and inquire openly and honestly if you might be having a bit of paranoia. I'm doubting anyone broke into your home to clone your wife's phone, nor are they likely listening in to your conversations via lightbulbs, window vibrations, or plain old normal bugs. My grandmother had this issue - convinced that the neighbors were lowering microphones down the chimney, etc.

Comment: I have a wood stove... works better than a shredder, and sensitive docs help light the fire. However, paranoia-fear is a matter of not knowing... if you know the deal, it's not paranoia, but it does evoke a certain feeling- maybe it's disgust. I helped build a very "serious" facility (and signed some confidentiality notices about that). So I already know some ways to protect a building, but I'm not at liberty to discuss those details even though that stuff is totally like, 10 years ago... and well, I wouldn't dare.

Comment: I'm not joking when I say this: have a functional CO detector in your home. Trace amounts of CO have been linked to psychosomatic issues.